# How can I disable the recursive search and instead use the type-ahead search in the Nautilus file picker?

Tags: nautilus, files, nemo

The recursive search in the file manager is extremely frustrating, I want to be able to instead use the type-ahead navigation when I'm opening/saving files (selecting the folder that matches what you type, instead of doing a full search through all the folders).

I have found [this guide](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2018/05/enable-nautilus-type-ahead-search-ubuntu) on enabling the type-ahead search in nautilus, but unfortunately it doesn't work in the file picker (the window that opens when you click Open/Save File in apps).

I tried replacing nautilus with Nemo, which has type-ahead search by default, but apparently there's no way to use Nemo as a file picker, people say that using nautilus is hardcoded into the apps.

Is there any solution or a workaround to this?